# Find Min: $A= \frac{bc}{a(b+2c)} +2 [ \frac{ac}{b(c+a)} + \frac {ab}{c(2a+b)}]$

Tags: inequality, optimization

Given $a,b,c>0$ such that: $ \frac{4a}{b} (1+ \frac{2c}{b}) + \frac{b}{a} (1+ \frac{c}{a})=6$
Find Min: $A= \frac{bc}{a(b+2c)} +2 [ \frac{ac}{b(c+a)} + \frac {ab}{c(2a+b)}]$
My try: Let: $\frac{4a}{b}=x ; \frac{2b}{c}=y; \frac{c}{a} =z$ then $xyz=8$

Answer (score 2):

The problem has no symmetry, so it is natural that a solution is cumbersome.

Put $$B=\frac{4a}{b} \left(1+ \frac{2c}{b}\right) + \frac{b}{a}\left(1+ \frac{c}{a}\right).$$  First of all we remark that a homogeneous substitution $a\to \lambda a$, $b\to \lambda b$, and $c\to \lambda c$ with any $\lambda>0$ does not change values of $A$ and $B$, so it suffice to consider only a case when $a=1$.

Equality $B=6$ is equivalent  to $c=\frac{6b^2-4b-b^3}{8+b^3}.$

The numerator should be positive, which is equivalent to $3-\sqrt{5}<b<3+\sqrt{5}$.

I used Matcad for the farther calculations.

We have $$A=A(b)=-2\frac{5b^6-40b^5+192b^4-432b^3+768b^2-640b+320}{(b^2-6b+4)(3b^2-2b+4)(b^2-2b+12)}.$$

[image]

When $b$ tends to an endpoint of the segment  $[3-\sqrt{5},3+\sqrt{5}]$ then $c$ tends to $0$, so $A(a,b,c)$ tends to $+\infty$.

To find the minimums of the function $A(b)$ we differentiate it

$A’(b)=4\frac{5b^10+56b^9+100b^8-1440b^7+4432b^6-17728b^4+23040b^3-6400b^2-14336b-5120}{(b^2-6b+4)^2(3b^2-2b+4)^2(b^2-2b+12)^2}$

and find the zeroes of the numerator

$$N(b)=5b^10+56b^9+100b^8-1440b^7+4432b^6-17728b^4+$$ $$23040b^3-6400b^2-14336b-5120=(b+2)(b-2)M(b),$$

where a polynomial $$M(b)=5b^8+56b^7+120b^6-1216b^5+4912b^4-4864b^3+1920b^2+3584b+1280$$ has no real roots. I hope that it can be shown without Mathcad, via estimations. To solve the problem it suffices to show that the polynomial $M(b)$ has no positive roots or, at least, no roots on the segment $[3-\sqrt{5},3+\sqrt{5}]$.

[image]

Thus the minimum of the function $A(b)$ on the segment $[3-\sqrt{5},3+\sqrt{5}]$ is attained at the point $b=2$. Then $c=1/2$ and

$$A(a,b,c)=A(1,2,1/2)=\min A=\frac 83.$$